Proving that $T_{n}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $p$ given a sample of i.i.d random variables
I am asked to show that the statistic $T(X):=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $p$, where $X_i\sim Geom(p)$ are i.i.d random variables.

Given a sample $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ I have to prove that $$\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n|T_{n}=t)$$ does not depend on the parameter $p$. $$\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n|T_{n}=t)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(T_{n}=t|X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n)\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n)}{\mathbb{P}(T_{n}=t)}$$ due to Bayes. Now, since the random variables are i.i.d the numerator comes up to be $$\mathbb{P}(T_{n}=t|X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n)\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{x_i-1}$$ since $\mathbb{P}(X_i=x_i)=p(1-p)^{x_i-1}$, $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{P}(T_{n}=t|X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n)=1$ if $t=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ and $0$ otherwise. So in the end my numerator is $p^n(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}$. For the denominator $$\mathbb{P}(T_{n}=t)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=t\Big)$$ where $T_{n}\sim NB(n,p)$, which one can prove by induction. So we have $$\mathbb{P}(T_{n}=t)=\binom{t-1}{n-1}p^n(1-p)^{t-n}$$ with $t\in\{n,n+1,\dots\}$. Finally, joining the expressions found we get $$\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n|T_{n}=t)=\frac{p^n(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}}{\binom{t-1}{n-1}p^n(1-p)^{t-n}}=\frac{(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}}{\binom{t-1}{n-1}(1-p)^t}=\frac{1}{\binom{t-1}{n-1}}$$ which does not depend on my parameter $p$.

Have I commited any errors along the way or do you see anything which you don't like? Please, confirm that my deduction is correct.
